# How to draw graph like two or more tables are connected by common values in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Problem -
If two or more database tables are joined and getting result table having attributes those are coming from parent tables and I want to show link connection in between them.

Attaching the images what exactly I want to show in D3js.

[image]

This is implemented with jQuery flowchart [plugin](http://sebastien.drouyer.com/jquery.flowchart-demo/), but I do not want to use jQuery.

[image]

Is anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: As a starter you could look at Sankey diagram for d3js. I believe that would look like something similar to what you are showing there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, yes I had looked Sankey graph but how could I draw tables that something like difficult as I feel. I am new to d3js.

Comment: Anitek, did you find an anwser? What is wrong with the flowchat plugin?